# MissingMethodException using native dll library in unity (currently a no-op)

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, mono, clips

I'm trying to integrate CLIPS library in unity beta (x64)  using mono 2.0 and net 4.6.

I'm using a net wrapper for clips: https://github.com/yifeitao/CLIPSNet

This project has two main files:
managedCLIPS.dll, which compiles clips C files into managed C++.
clipsNET.dll, the actual wrapper for mono, which uses managedclips.

I can compile both files and drag to unity, but when trying to run it I get some errors: MissingMethodException: Method contains unsupported native code

https://imgur.com/ESLJdGT

I used MoMa: mono migration analyzer and and it says "Methods called marked with [MonoTodo]: 5" and Currently a no-op

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiYv2.jpg

¿Any ideas of how can I solve this?

Thanks!